# Fierz identity for symplectic group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is known that for the fundamental matrix representation of SU(N), with normalization given by
$$
{\rm Tr}(T^iT^j)=\frac{1}{2}\delta^{ij}
$$
there is a Fierz identity:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N^2-1}T^i_{ab}T^i_{cd}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\delta^{ad}\delta^{bc}-\frac{1}{N}\delta^{ab}\delta^{cd}\right)
$$
where $T^i$ is the matrix representation of the $i$th generator of SU(N) in the fundamental representation.

For the symplectic group Sp(N), what is the analogous Fierz identity? Namely, suppose $T^i$ is the matrix representation of the $i$th generator of Sp(N) in the fundamental representation, can
$$
\sum_iT^i_{ab}T^i_{cd}
$$
be written as something like above?

Comment: What does "the $i$th generator of" a Lie group mean?

Comment: For example, SU(2) has 3 generators, and I call them the 1st, 2nd and 3rd generator, respectively

Comment: Do you mean the Lie algebra every time you refer to the Lie group?  Even if so, how do you know which of the many possible bases to use?

Comment: It would surely depend on how you pick the basis.